# Add custom properties to ABP UserFriendlyException

Tags: error-handling, aspnetboilerplate

I am using aspnetboilerplate and I want to add additional data while throwing UserFriendlyException. ex. ErrorReferenceNumber
I have created my own exception class that inherits UserFriendlyException (also tried AbpException and Exception) then I added my custom properties.

but I am unable to get the new custom properties available with the response. after investigation, I found that I have to replace IExceptionToErrorInfoConverter with my own implementation.

I did but still not working so I want to know how can I override the configuration and force it to run my custom implementation? or I'm missing something?

Code

```
public class BusinessException : AbpException, IHasLogSeverity, IHasErrorCode
    {
        public string Details { get; private set; }

        public int Code { get; set; }

        public string ReferenceNumber { get; set; }

        public string MessageArabic { get; set; }

        public LogSeverity Severity { get; set; }


        public BusinessException()
        {
            Severity = LogSeverity.Warn;
        }

        public BusinessException(string message)
            : base(message)
        {
            Severity = LogSeverity.Warn;
        }

        public BusinessException(string message, LogSeverity severity)
            : base(message)
        {
            Severity = severity;
        }

        public BusinessException(int code, string message)
            : this(message)
        {
            Code = code;
        }

        public BusinessException(string message, string details)
            : this(message)
        {
            Details = details;
        }

        public BusinessException(int code, string message, string details)
            : this(message, details)
        {
            Code = code;
        }

        public BusinessException(int code, string referenceNumber, string message, string messageArabic)
            : this(code, message)
        {
            ReferenceNumber = referenceNumber;
            MessageArabic = messageArabic;
        }

        public BusinessException(int code, string referenceNumber, string message, string messageArabic, string details)
            : this(code, message, details)
        {
            ReferenceNumber = referenceNumber;
            MessageArabic = messageArabic;
        }

        public BusinessException(string message, Exception innerException)
            : base(message, innerException)
        {
            Severity = LogSeverity.Warn;
        }

        public BusinessException(string message, string details, Exception innerException)
            : this(message, innerException)
        {
            Details = details;
        }
    }


public class MyErrorInfoConverter : IExceptionToErrorInfoConverter
    {
        public IExceptionToErrorInfoConverter Next { set; private get; }

        public ErrorInfo Convert(Exception exception)
        {
             return new MyErrorInfo(5000,"ABC100022545", "My SpecificMessage 1", "My Specific Message 2");
            
        }
    }
```

In PreInitialize for the Core Project, I added

```
Configuration.ReplaceService<IExceptionToErrorInfoConverter, MyErrorInfoConverter>(Abp.Dependency.DependencyLifeStyle.Transient);
```

My application still not able to use the customized class and it throws "An internal error occurred during your request!" exception message. What am I missing?

Comment: Is there any additional logs or could you try wrapping your code with a `try` `catch` clause